# PHP Open Source MySQL Query Builder?

Tags: php, mysql, open-source, builder

Do you know an open source Mysql Query Builder made in PHP please ? 
Like "Query Builder for MySQL by dbForge "?

http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/querybuilder/benefits.html

Comment: have you heard about MySQL GUI Tools from MySQL itself and PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: yes but i don't think that was made in PHP

Comment: PHPMyAdmin is a PHP tool, though GUI tools are standalones

Answer (score 2):

[MySQL Query Builder](https://github.com/indeyets/MySQL-Query-Builder)

[MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)

These are just two.

Comment: Yes, I already saw these, thanks.
unfortunaly i have no other choice to develop myself a tool

Answer (score 0):

Try using [SQLyog's](http://www.webyog.com/en/downloads.php) powerful Query Builder. Although [SQLyog](http://www.webyog.com/en/downloads.php) is not in PHP, but it is really easy and intuitive to use. [image: SQLyog Query Builder screenshot]

Comment: Thanks to you, i've wanted a tools in php able to create extract. I finally create my own tool. Now i want to publish it on github, I will take time and publish it later certainly.

Answer (score 0):

The best one I found is [QueryBuilder](https://github.com/nediam/QueryBuilder)

Comment: Project is outdated? 404 error...

Comment: https://github.com/nediam/QueryBuilder

Answer (score 0):

i think that the query builder is a php code that simplifies the writing of sql queries like this https://github.com/lytc/mysql-query-builder/tree/master/library/Qb
for light websites it's useless to use an ORM so a query builder should do it , or even a DBAL , 
it helps a lot with manipulating the data when retrieved and inserting data to the data Base .